# JQuery add find method dynamically

Tags: jquery

I get a array with variable length. The first element is always the parent. After him the children to find, to find the children and so on. I need to add find methods dynamically. Or is there a better method.

```
MyArray:{'.grand_parent','.older_child','.younger_child'}
```

generate this:

```
$(#base).parent('.grand_parent').find('.older_child').find('.younger_child');
```

What about this array:

```
LongerArray:{'.grand_parent','.child1','.child2','.child3','child4'}
```

Comment: Actually that's an invalid object not an array.

Comment: i know :) that was just pseudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first element of the array should be passed to [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method and other elements should be passed to `.find()` method, there is no need to call several `.find()` methods, you can [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements and pass the result to the `.find()` method as one selector:

```
$('#base').parent(arr[0]) // .parent(".grand_parent")
          .find(arr.slice(1).join(' ')); // .find(".child1 .child2 .child3 .child4")
```

Note that `.parent()` method doesn't select grandparent elements, it only selects the first-level parent element of the selected element(if a selector is passed to it, it selects the parent element only if it matches the specified selector), if you want to select parent/grandparent element(s) according to your needs you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method instead.